# In Python difference in __dict__ between object() and class myClass(object)

Tags: python

I was messing around with dynamic attributes and I noticed I could not use the __dict__ attribute if I created the object directly from the object() class but if I create a new class that is a direct descendent of object I can access the __dict__ attribute. Why the difference?

Examples:

> ```
> # This gives an AttributeError  
> o = object()
> o.__dict__
> ```

```
# This works: prints {}
class myClass(object):
    pass
o = myClass()
o.__dict__
```

Comment: Fiddling with `__dict__` directly is almost always unneeded and a bad idea. Dynamic attributes name are usually better done as dictionary keys, but justified in a few cases - but you can just use `setattr` in those cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`object` is implemented in C and doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute. (Not all Python objects have it either; look up [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#slots)).

Comment: @Jamie Note that you can't assign random attributes on an instance obtained by doing `object()`, either, while you can with an instance of `myClass`. In fact there's not a lot you *can* do with an instance of `object` that isn't an instance of any other class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why it works for your class but not the original `object` class. I'd assume that when your class get initialized, it creates __dict__.

Using this code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def main():
    print 'OBJECT:', dir(object())
    print
    print 'TEST:', dir(Test())
    return
```

Came up with this output:

```
OBJECT: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__']

TEST: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__weakref__']
```

As you can see, __dict__, __module__, and __weakref__ are in the Test object but not the base object

Comment: It's an inherent part of Python - it's up to the class definition whether or not they want to provide a __dict__ attribute or not (leaving it out can save a fair bit of space per instance). Since __dict__ is included in instances by default, you have to take action specifically at class definition time to avoid providing one.